# In LWC OSS what is this.allsession while assigning to arrya

Tags: lwc-oss

I am learning LWC OSS and in the trailhead, I am unable to understand, the use of this.allSessions in the below code while assigning the result to the array variable of "sessions = []"

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { getSessions } from 'data/sessionService';
export default class SessionList extends LightningElement {
  sessions = [];
  connectedCallback() {
    getSessions().then(result => {
      this.sessions = this.allSessions = result;
    });
  }
}
```

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-your-first-app-with-lightning-web-components-open-source/create-the-session-list-web-component

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a missing line of code in this module, which I believe may cause runtime errors.

The class should start off as:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { getSessions } from 'data/sessionService';
export default class SessionList extends LightningElement {
  sessions = [];
  allSessions = [];
  connectedCallback() {
    getSessions().then(result => {
      this.sessions = this.allSessions = result;
    });
  }
}
```

This variable is used to store all loaded sessions, while the sessions property is used to display the (possibly filtered) list of sessions.

I did test this in node without the `allSessions = [];`, though, and it appeared to work, so it may actually not be necessary, but I'd do this as a matter of self-documenting.