# LWC problem with understanding promise function

Tags: lightning-web-components

in the second picture I am using fetch API to get some data and saving it in the getSession and exporting it. My question is, can someone help me understand the first screenshot, why do we use once again .then() method from getSession(), and why do we use the following expression inside the then method(this.sessions = this.allSessions = data;). And, where do we get that this.allSessions from?

[image: Why is the syntax inside the then method like this? this.sessions = this.allSessions = result]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In LWC OSS what is this.allsession while assigning to arrya](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330182/in-lwc-oss-what-is-this-allsession-while-assigning-to-arrya)

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please copy/paste code as text instead of (or in addition to) screenshots. An image of text with no accompanying actual text is not good accessibility-wise for folks with screen readers. Plus it makes it harder for anyone to help if they want to copy your code and put it in a sandbox or code editor. The SE editor makes it easy to format code  - just put three "backticks" (```) above and below the block of code.

Answer (score 0):

> why do we use once again .then() method from getSession(),

Because you presumably want the list of sessions returned from calling that method.

> why do we use the following expression inside the then method(this.sessions = this.allSessions = data;).

Again, because you presumably want to save the results to your class.

> where do we get that this.allSessions from?

Nowhere. It's not defined, and should not be in this code.